# Generating equally distributed voxel points based on a given point

Tags: numerics

I have a list of seed points  that each of them indicates the bottom-left value of a voxel. In order to improve the accuracy of my function, I need to equally sample my points and apply my functions on them.For instance, with 0.5 step-size, I should get 27 seed  points on the related voxel. Here is an example:

```
seedpoints= {{33, 55, 12}, {33, 55, 13}, {33, 56, 12}, {33, 56, 13}, {33, 57, 12}, {33, 57, 13}, {33, 58, 12}, {33, 58, 13}, {33, 59, 11}, {33, 59, 12}, {100, 70, 14}, {100, 71, 12}, {100, 71, 13}, {100, 71, 14}, {101, 68, 13}, {101, 69, 12}, {101, 69, 13}, {101, 70, 12}, {101, 70, 13}};
(*h=stepsize*)
```

Based on the first seed point, I should nearly get:

```
desiredoutput={{33,55,12},{33+h,55,12},{33+2h,55,12},{33,55+h,12},{33+h,55+h,12},...,{33+2h,55+2h,12+2h}};(*all points must be on the related voxel,meanly 33+2h<=34 && 55+2h<=56 &&12+2h<=13*)
```

I hope, it is sufficiently clear. Any help or idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this way:

```
hh = Tuples[{0, h, 2 h}, 3];
Plus[hh, ConstantArray[#, 27]] & /@ seedpoints // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> {{33,55,12},{33,55,12+h},{33,55,12+2 h},{33,55+h,12},{33,55+h,12+h},{33,55+h,12+2 h},{33,55+2 h,12},{33,55+2 h,12+h},<<498>>,{101+2 h,70,13+2 h},{101+2 h,70+h,13},{101+2 h,70+h,13+h},{101+2 h,70+h,13+2 h},{101+2 h,70+2 h,13},{101+2 h,70+2 h,13+h},{101+2 h,70+2 h,13+2 h}}

Comment: That's nearly what I want, thanks.

Comment: @cesm So maybe I can improve it, tell me why it is "nearly" :)

Comment: Oops, sorry. There had been a confusion, that's exactly what I want:) Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider putting the sample points at the centers of the subvoxels, instead of at their corners. This would both reduce the step size and eliminate duplicate sample points for adjacent voxels. For instance, in Kuba's code use
    `n = 3; hh = Tuples[Range[1,2n,2],3]/(2n);`
You still have 27 sample points/voxel, but `h` = 1/3 instead of 1/2.

Comment: Thanks, that's another point of view.